# How to make a wall post with an "ACTION" from facebook js sdk

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm trying to make a post with an Action. I already know how to make a post to the wall. My problem is adding the action to the post. I have searched on internet, but I can't seem to find the Action in a js /ID/feed post.

Image 1 - No action

[image: Image witout a post]

Image 2 - Action - Vote on pictures

[image]

The action is the "Vote on photos" link under the post.

I have tried many things like:

```
var action = {
    name: 'Vote on photos',
    link: link
}

var attachment = {
name: message,
caption: caption,
link:link,
picture:pixUIurl,
action: Array()
}

attachment.action.push(action);

FB.api('/'+id+'/feed', 'post', attachment, function(response) {
    if (!response || response.error) {
        //alert('Error occured');
    } else {
        //alert('Post ID: ' + response.id);
    }
});
```

and

```
var action = {
    name: 'Vote on photos',
    link: link
}

var attachment = {
    name: message,
    caption: caption,
    link:link,
    picture:pixUIurl,
    action: function (){
        0:action
    }
}
FB.api('/'+id+'/feed', 'post', attachment, function(response) {
    if (!response || response.error) {
        //alert('Error occured');
    } else {
        //alert('Post ID: ' + response.id);
    }
});
```

But I can't get the action working. Does someone know how to post with an action from js?

Tank you.

For help, the documentation has http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/.

Also, in the php sdk you can add an action like:

```
$attachment = array(
    'name' => $message,
    'caption' => $caption,
    'link' => $link,
    'picture' => $picture1,
    'actions' => array(
        array(
            'name'=>'Vote on photos',
            'link' => _CANVAS_PAGE
        )
    )
);

$result = $facebook->api('/user_id/feed/', 'post', $parameters );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like that :

```
var attachment = {
name: message,
caption: caption,
link:link,
picture:pixUIurl,
actions: [{
  name: "Vote on photos",
  link: "_CANVAS_PAGE"}]
}
```

You have some examples in the [JavaScript Test Console](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/console/)

Comment: Thank you. I just saw it had an example on the fb.ui. I didn't thought about looking at that before asking.
Anyway, I think this is the first example of this on stackoverflow, so its still a good post.